# Issue with 301 redirect in IIS

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, virtual-directory

I have a simple ASP.NET 3.5 application running under IIS7 under a virtual directory. So the URL of my app is like http://site.com/app. I want to 301-redirect the request to site.com/app/default.aspx to site.com/app for better SEO.
Is there any solutions with .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite).  It's the perfect tool for this situation and there are some wizards that will help with the basic SEO redirects.